# Crontab Process Not Executing Properly

Tags: redis, cron

When I run the following command from the command line it works fine:

```
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli KEYS "users_*" | xargs redis-cli DEL > /home/Email/logs/deletelog.log 2>&1
```

However if I run it via a cron for the root user it doesn't seem to execute correctly. I expect that there is a permissions issue somewhere. How can I check this out or fix the issue?

I run the following in crontab -e

```
45      23       *       *       *       /usr/local/bin/redis-cli KEYS "users_*" | xargs redis-cli DEL > /home/Email/logs/deletelog.log 2>&1
```

If I output the error to a log file I am getting the following:

```
xargs: redis-cli: No such file or directory
```

But I can run it from the command line using:

```
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli KEYS "users_*" | xargs redis-cli DEL > /home/Email/logs/deletelog.log 2>&1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, I was missing /usr/local/bin/ in the pipe. The correct command should be:

```
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli KEYS "users_*" | xargs /usr/local/bin/redis-cli DEL > /home/Email/logs/deletelog.log 2>&1
```